How to drive single or multiple pvdf film type piezo actuators
this is going to be a little long but I wanted to include as much detail as possible in my question. There is a TLDR at the end.
I am part of a design team focused on making a vibration and audio playing device using PVDF piezoelectric sheets. The idea is to apply a voltage across the film in order to get it to vibrate, and by controlling the frequency of the vibration, audible sound can also be played through the film. We are basically creating a speaker in the form of a 15"x45" acrylic sheet by either laminating a PVDF film of the same size or several small films (1"x1") around the perimeter of the acrylic sheet.
In the past versions of this project, a simple audio amplifier designed for speakers was used in conjunction with a step-up transformer to get the required voltages for the film, typically in the range of 100-200 V. This has had varying success with a transformer only working a few times before being blown.
In my research I have found this device, a piezo driver which uses a boost-converter and differential amplifier among other circuitry to create an all-in-one audio amplifier capable of outputting 200V. Is this the best way to drive our piezoelectric film and can it drive multiple films connected in series or parallel?
Are there cheaper alternatives for driving piezo film? I know with the right electrical knowledge, we can probably build out own amplifier using op-amps, boost-converters, and transistors but we are mechanical engineering students so our electrical knowledge is limited.
Someone from another forum also recommended this amplifier, a cheap $13 amplifier with 150 W power rating, but there is no info on its output voltage. Theoretically, piezoelectric materials require very little current, in the scale of milliamps, so a 150W amplifier should be able to deliver 150V if running 1A right? I have also had mixed reactions to using a low power amplifier with a step-up transformer to get the desired voltage, with some saying this only works in theory, not application, and others saying to do this instead of using a high-power audio amplifier since 100-200V audio amplifiers have risks of fire and electrocution if used improperly.
TLDR: Looking for the best way to drive a single or multiple PVDF piezoelectric film for making vibrations and sound.

Transformer failing? If that is your problem, then you may solve this with a proper transformer design. You should also understand the complex impedance (or admittance) versus frequency of your transducer. If you have the complex admittance, your project can be easily simulated in SPICE using AC analysis. Your assumption of the transducer only requiring a few milliamps is may be flawed unless you have a very small area.

While the DC current required for a piezoelectric transducer is low, the AC current can be quite large. A PVDF element can be pretty well modeled by a capacitor so you can calculate the required current. You want to be sure the driver can supply that current. Putting multiple elements in parallel just makes the current requirement greater.
The chip for the high voltage driver is a TI chip and the specs give the maximum load capacitance for 500 Hz. This is an indirect way of specifying the maximum load current.
